# Should the host name array be declared MAXHOSTNAMELEN+1 for gethostname?

Tags: c, sockets, posix, buffer-overrun

I am fixing a call to `gethostname()` where the old code declared the `hostName` array to be 10 characters causing a boundary error since the host names are bigger then that.  My fix was to declare `hostName` using `MAXHOSTNAMELEN` (which my platform's `parm.h` declares to be 64).  Another programmer is now saying that the array needs to be declared as `hostName[MAXHOSTNAMELEN+1]` and *cleared out* because (from his email message):

> This is from the man page:
>   POSIX.1-2001 guarantees that
>          "Host names (not including the terminating null byte) are limited to HOST_NAME_MAX bytes”
>
> So to handle all situations, you must add one to the buffer size and initialize the buffer with null characters.

Now every example I have see online is doing a `char hostName[MAXHOSTNAMELEN]` and since the call either works or it doesn't, it makes no sense to me to zero out the `hostName` array or to initialize it to null since if it works the array is set to the host name and if it doesn't the call returns with a error.

What is the robust way to declare or initialize the parameters to `gethostname()`?

Answer (score 2):

The [POSIX spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/gethostname.html) says:

> The returned name shall be null-terminated, except that if namelen is an insufficient length to hold the host name, then the returned name shall be truncated and it is unspecified whether the returned name is null-terminated.
>
> Host names are limited to {HOST_NAME_MAX} bytes.

On your system, I assume `MAXHOSTNAMELEN` corresponds to what the spec calls `HOST_NAME_MAX`.  Therefore, making the buffer `MAXHOSTNAMELEN+1` bytes *and passing that size to `gethostname()`* should guarantee that you don't have to zero-initialize.

If you didn't zero-initialize, *and* you didn't have that extra `+1` byte, you might encounter failures due to it being "unspecified whether the returned name is null-terminated" when the buffer isn't long enough.

That said, if your platform isn't strictly standards-compliant, zero-filling might be useful or necessary.  The programmer who told you to do so has a reason — is that reason specific to a quirk of your platform?

**Edit** The [spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/gethostname.html) also says that the `nameLen` parameter is the "size of the array pointed to by the *name* argument".  Since it is the size of the *array* and not the size of the *hostname* to be stored in that array, providing space in the *array* for the `\0` terminator is a good practice.  The majority of domain name labels have not been 64 bytes, historically, so code without the `+1` has probably worked fine in the past.  Safer to use the `+1`, though, and not have to assume or guess.

**Edit 2** I suppose "insufficient length to hold the host name" is arguably ambiguous.  However, the spec cannot intend that `gethostname()` should write off the end of the supplied array.  Therefore, I take "insufficient length to hold the host name" to mean "insufficient length to hold the host name *plus the null-terminator byte.*"  That's my personal interpretation, but it is consistent with my experience.

Comment: No, just that I expected the MAXHOSTNAMELEN size to include the NULL terminator slot and that all the examples I have seen online for the call have never do a MAXHOSTNAMELEN+1.  I would think if it was a problem someone would have do the MAXHOSTNAMELEN+1 way.  The gethostname() is being done in 2 other C++ classes so If it really should be done with a +1 then I need to make the case to fix the other 2 so we are consistent in the software.

Comment: @user3416126 I have seen `+1` in other API calls so it doesn't surprise me.  I will edit momentarily to add one more spec quote.  **Edited** And yes, I certainy support consistency throughout the codebase!